# How to run every possible letter in a string python

Tags: python-3.x, string, brute-force

I am wanting a program that takes in a string. For example, let's say: staff. Now what the program **should** do is run every single letter in that string. For example: I tried to give each letter a value

```
alphkey = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

and so on... It should not be able to have a string combo like aaaa because the word staff has 2 f's in it and the rest are different. It should not be able to give for example two letters assigned to another letter. so ff in staff could be the same but the rest different.

I am just asking how could I do this on my own.
For example:
staff could return dsegg or welbb or even staff.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop.

```py
chars = input('str')
charcodes = []
for char in chars:
    charcodes.append(char)
```

Now you can access the values from the `charcodes` `list`.

```py
print('The first character was', charcodes[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you're trying to achieve, but this might be it:

```
alphkey = 'abcd'
array = []

for character in alphkey:
    array.append(character)
```

You can then access individual characters using their numerical position, for example:
`array[2]` would return the character 'c'.

Answer (score 1):

Even more easier way is call `list` over the input

```
In [32]: chars = input('str:')
    ...: charcodes = list(chars)
str: hello

In [33]: charcodes[0]
Out[33]: 'h'

In [34]: charcodes
Out[34]: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```